# How data will get selected on click of enter key with delimiter

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I have a combobox and I am trying to select value from combo on click of enter and value should display with dilemiter as soon as I click on enter.

Right Now I am using mouse to select the combo value and delimiter coming after selection of next value. I tried with many methods but not getting suceess. Can anybody please help me.

I created a fiddle. [My Fiddler](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1h7b)

Comment: FYI Multiselect is deprecated http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#cfg-multiSelect what about using tag field? https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1h89

Comment: @pagep Yes, but `multiSelect : true` is working don't know how. Also if I use tagfield `delimiter : ";",` is not working and typing is also not working.

Comment: It's still working, if you don't plan to upgrade to new Ext version I guess it's ok to use it. But when it's deprecated it can stop working in the next version. The typing is working for me on Chrome. Btw why do you need the delimiter as described anyway? Because when you get the data from there, you get the value in format of array.

Comment: @pagep See in `tagfield` when I enter value I automatically getting value with cross, I want exactly same but not with cross, with delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question, you need to select combo when cursor is focus on combo. So you need to expand it manually. You can refer this. [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1hbb)